# How do I tell if a TextView created in my SQLite database was clicked?

Tags: java, android, sql, textview

I have a database with team names and team numbers(both stored as strings - the numbers sometimes have letters in them)

I want it so when you click the "Open" button, it'll bring up a popup that will have all of the teams' names and numbers, and if you click one, it will close the popup and set both editText's to the name & number.

```
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            ScoutingFormData info = new ScoutingFormData(this);
            info.open();
            ScrollView scr = info.getData();
            info.close();
            d.addContentView(scr, null);
            d.show();
```

That's from the main program, when you click "Open", this happens. ScoutingFormData is my SQLite database, and here's getData:

```
    public ScrollView getData() {
    String[] columns=new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME,KEY_NUM};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    ScrollView result=new ScrollView(null);
    int iID = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int iNum = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NUM);
    LinearLayout vertlay = new LinearLayout(null);
    vertlay.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
        TextView tv=new TextView(null);
        tv.setText(c.getString(iNum)+"  "+c.getString(iName));
        vertlay.addView(tv);
    }
    result.addView(vertlay);
    return result;
}
```

So this builds the dialog, but how do I make it so the main program(the top code) will know when one of these TextViews have been clicked?

Side question: when making a View(like LinearLayout vertlay = new LinearLayout(null);), what context am I supposed to be using? I don't fully understand what a 'context' is, so I'm really at a loss of what to replace "null" with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I make it so the main program(the top code) will know when one of these TextViews have been clicked?

Simply make `tv` `clickable` and add an `OnClickListener`.

> Side question: what context am I supposed to be using?

You hinted that `getData()` is in your database adapter class `ScoutingFormData`, save a reference to the Context passed to the Constructor and reuse it later:

```
private Context mContext;
public ScoutingFormData(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}
```

All together:

```
TextView tv=new TextView(mContext);
tv.setClickable(true);
tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Do something
    }
});
```